Не работает звук Linux Fedora [Попытки решения были]
Ситуация распространённая. Использовал все команды, которые смог и ничего не получилось. Снизу предоставлен файл с выводами всех команд, и с моей попыткой решения. Динамики работают - в таком приложении, как в майнкрафт звук есть (там динамики настраиваются вручную). А так нигде звука нет. Нет надписи фиктивный выход. Теперь в принципе не видит динамики. Несколько раз перезагружал, пытался тестить наушники в настройках - ничего.
Pastebin ссылка
Что смог поместил на сайт:
=== Данные для диагностики звуковых проблем ===
 
Вывод lspci -v:
 
(pavucontrol:22285): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:42:59.321: Unable to register the application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not activate remote peer 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry': unit failed
 
(pavucontrol:22285): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 20:43:00.092: Unable to register the application: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not activate remote peer 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry': unit failed
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3805
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
 
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3810
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 4000-4fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: a3000000-a40fffff [size=17M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 90000000-a1ffffff [size=288M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3810
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 39f5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 147
    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
 
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3827
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy
 
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3858
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at a4520000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features
 
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3803
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a4521000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
 
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at a4500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
 
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3825
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at a451c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a4522000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
 
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3809
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 8f800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3807
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 8f801000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
    Memory at a4525000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
 
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380c
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at a451e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a452a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at a4529000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
 
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 381b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 6000-6fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: a4400000-a44fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 8f900000-8fafffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 381b
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 381f
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 7000-7fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: a4300000-a43fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 8fb00000-8fcfffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 381f
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Null
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3822
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 3000-3fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: a4200000-a42fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 8fd00000-8fefffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), IntMsgNum 0
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3822
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [150] Precision Time Measurement
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [250] Downstream Port Containment
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport


Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он станет недоступным или навсегда закрытым

у вас, кажется, установлены как pulseaudio, так и pipewire. По своему небольшому опыту знаю, что он они могут конфликтовать друг с другом (что логично). Попробуйте удалить один из пакетов.
В репозиториях дистрибутива archlinux есть пакет pipewire-pulseaudio, который позволяет pipewire подменять собой pulseaudio -- так pulseaudio отстраняется без вреда для системы (приложения, требующие pa будут удовлетворены и pw). Возможно, в репозиториях вашего дистрибутива есть подобное ПО. В крайнем случай, подобное ПО, уверен, можно и за пределами репозитория найти.

Спасибо, помогло)
